# paint qgraphicsitem in front of its parent

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I want to `paint` a `round rectangle` using the paint function in `QGraphicsItem`, I have a parent item and I want to paint its child in front of it, but I don't know how to do it? 
And I have another problem, I want to list this items base on their parent position, but positions are static, how can I position items based on the parent position?

My paint function :

```
void flipedWidget::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *w)
{
    Q_UNUSED(w)
    Q_UNUSED(option)
    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    QBrush *brush;
    if(!m_color.isEmpty())
        brush = new QBrush(QColor(m_color)); // set background color
    else
        brush = new QBrush("#cccccc");
    painter->setBrush(*brush);
    painter->drawRoundedRect(boundingRect(), 10, 10);
    delete brush;
}
```

Comment: These are two questions. One topic = one question. What exactly doesn't work in your code? What do you do with the painter and option* before passing them onto this function (show the code)?

Comment: Have you checked to see what values boundingRect() returns?  Maybe it is off-screen, or very small.  Also, there's no need to allocate the QBrush with new and then delete it; just allocate it on the stack instead.

Comment: Children are painted before parents and positioned relative to parents by default. You probably do something else wrong.